# Firebird custom installation

Tags: command-line, firebird, inno-setup

I want to deploy a firebird installation, and thus will launch it from my installer using command-line parameters. I read Inno Setup's documentation but still can't get it to work.

I just want to install a "Super server" with no documentation or whatsoever.

Here's what I have so far

```
Firebird-2.1.2.18118_0_Win32.exe /sp- /silent /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /nocancel /noicons /components="Super Server binary"
```

But it won't install the server. If I remove the /components it does install the server but install other developer stuff, which customers don't need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read installation_scripted.txt in C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\doc

> /COMPONENTS="comma separated list of
>   component names"
>
> Choose from -
>   ServerComponent\SuperServerComponent,
>                   ServerComponent\ClassicServerComponent,
>                   ServerComponent,
>                   DevAdminComponent and
>                   ClientComponent
>
> Overrides the default components
>   settings. Using this command line
>   parameter causes Setup to
>   automatically select a custom type. A
>   full   install requires combining
>   components. For example:
>
> /COMPONENTS="ServerComponent\SuperServerComponent,ServerComponent,DevAdminComponent,ClientComponent"
>
> would be required for a full
>   install.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following and it works fine, however I need to install to a custom directory and also change the server option

```
string installerFilePath = @"C:\BennaOlivier\Randoms\Delter\Firebird\FirebirdMainInstaller\MainInstaller\MainInstaller\Firebird X64\FirebirdInstallX64\Firebird-2.5x64.exe";
            Process installerProcess = new Process();

            installerProcess = Process.Start(installerFilePath, Arguments);

            while (installerProcess.HasExited == false)
            {
                //indicate progress to user 
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception FBX64)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(FBX64.Message);
            throw;
        }public const string comps = @"ServerComponent\ClassicServerComponent,ServerComponent,ClientComponent";

    public const string Arguments = "/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES";
```

Comment: The Arguments I pass is as follows, however it does not install to the directory specified and also it restarts after Firebird is installed

"/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES / DIR @c:\program files\firebird\ / NORESTART ServerComponent\ClassicServerComponent, ServerComponent,ClientComponent"